# Add all users in AD-Group to the local wheel group

Tags: centos, pam, su, active-directory, sssd

We have limited '*su*' to users that are in the wheel group and are now looking to permit certain users that are in a particular AD-Group.

The users that we want to permit to use the program '*su*' are in the AD-Group: "test-group@example.com".

We are utilizing the following configuration in */etc/pam.d/su*:

```
auth            required        pam_wheel.so use_uid
```

How do we achieve so that every user that is a member of AD-group "test-group@example.com" can use the program '*su*'?

Comment: Have you considered `sudo`?, it is designed for this use-case, if give finer-grain control, and has logging.

Comment: Yes we are using sudo and will always use sudo. However, we don't want to completely disable su but limit it to certain users that are in said AD group.